# FEMM simulation not returning expected force from electromagnet

Tags: electromagnetism, femm

I have an array of 8 air-cored electromagnets. Each one activates sequentially(with previous ones staying activated) to pull the N42 Neodymium magnet array to the end of the array, with the force adding each time as the successive fields of the electromagnets add. Each electromagnet has internal diameter of 10mm, external diameter of 40mm and consists of 150 turns of 18 AWG magnet wire running 10A of current. One individual solenoid produces a force of 30N. Therefore, 2 should produce 60N, 3 90N, 4 120N and so on until 8(which would produce 240N). However the forces seem not to add as expected. I am still looking for answers, as the current ones do not fully clear up my confusion.

Why is this happening, is my simulation set up wrong, or is my understanding wrong?

The forces look like this for each stage...

Electromagnet 1: 30N

Electromagnet 2: 60N

Electromagnet 3: 80N

Electromagnet 4: 88N

Electromagnet 5: 91N

Electromagnet 6: 88N

Electromagnet 7: 80N

Electromagnet 8: 64N

Here is a simulation of the first stage. The other "electromagnets" are set to air so they have no effect. I have super-imposed the stage number.

[image]

Stage 2, where forces add as expected:

[image]

Stage 5, where force peaks, but should be 180N, not 91N, this non-linearity is what confuses me.

[image]

Stage 8, where force has decreased from peak to 64N.
[image]

This is how my simulation is set up. The circuit "coil" is set to series and 10A.

[image]

Comment: `One individual solenoid produces a force of 30N. Therefore, 2 should produce 60N` -one woman takes 9 months to have a baby, so two should take 4.5 months? Your magnet calculation assumes they are in the same physical space. They are not in the same physical space, so don't add up linearly.

Comment: My reasoning is that since, they are of the same properties, then each solenoid individually should produces 30N. Therefore, once the magnet array has passed through the first coil, and the second one is activated, the second one will produce another 30N force on top of the existing 30N force that the first coil is providing. Since forces add as vectors and both should produce 30N in the same direction, total force should be 60N. This seems to initially be backed up by the fact the force is 60N in second screenshot, so why doesn't this trend continue for the rest?

Comment: Due to the gap between your stages you're not really making the magnetic field stronger, you're just redirecting the magnetic field. It's very similar to putting multiple individual magnets together. Putting multiple magnets together like (N - S)(N - S)(N - S) doesn't make it much stronger than just one (N - S) at the N or S pole.

Comment: Hmmm... What do you mean by gaps, because on the simulation there are meant to be no gaps between the stages. Also, I am pretty sure the fields strengthen each other, because I initially ran the simulation with 1 magnet in the magnet array, and the force was significantly weaker than with 8 magnets in the magnet array. Also... https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775581/do-magnetic-fields-combine-and-how-to-calculate-force-of-attraction-repulsion-be

Answer (score 1):

That is expected. The electromagnets are not colocated. The ones close to the middle of the magnet array don't do much. The ones further back pull the array backwards!

I suggest that instead of simulating it, try holding the magnet array in your hand, and a single electromagnet in the other, and move it along the length of the magnet to see what it'll do. IMHO intuition here is worth a lot - these are the kinds of experiments me & my buddies did as kids with magnets scavenged from old speakers and such.

Instead you should have one electromagnet optimized for maximum N/(A*turns) and drive it with PWM and flyback diode to easily get currents less than full rating.

Comment: Why don't the ones in the middle of the magnet array do much though, and why do previous one pull it back? Once each coil is activated, shouldn't their fields combine to make a larger one in the same way the magnet array forms one larger field, (as the gap between the coils is minute, in this ideal scenario I have simulated it is 0), effectively forming the larger electromagnet you mentioned.  Since magnet array is not at or past the centre of the coil array by coil 8, there shouldn't be any "suck-back"?

Also, the PWM is an interesting idea. What benefits does it bring, and?